# Having trouble understanding blatantly non-private definition because of Little-o notation

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, security, definitions

I was pretty confident that I understand asymptotic notation until now. However, I am having a hard time understanding some basic definition that use asymptotic notation, specially little-o.

> Definition 8.1.A mechanism is blatantly non-private if an adversary can
> construct a candidate database 'c' that agrees with the real database 'd' in
> all but o(n) entries, i.e.,‖c−d‖0∈o(n).

A bit of context. 'd' is a database where each row is one individual 'i' with 'n' individuals in total. the database has just one column representing some important questions. The values of the column can be 0 or 1.
'c' is a candidate database, a database that will try to be as similar as possible to the database 'd', it has the same structure one row for each individual and values for the column of {0,1}. Both are treated as a vector.

I watched a lecture and the informal description of the professor was "database 'c' will agree with database 'd' in 99,9..% of the cases".

But my interpretation of the definition is exactly the opposite "database 'c' will agree with database 'd' in all entries except 99,9..%".

My definition seems a bit odd to a "blantly" non-private mechanism. But I cannot understand how "except o(n)" would mean that a minority of the entries would not be equal in both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation of your professor is "intuitively correct" (but still formally wrong).
The notation $o(n)$ denotes the set of functions that grow less than linearly with $n$.

That definition means that, if we look at databases $d$ whose number of entries $n$ grows towards infinity, the candidate database $c$ will agree with $d$ in all but a vanishingly small fraction of the entries.

Notice that if $c$ agrees with $d$ "only" on $99.9\%$ of the $n$  entries, then the number of disagreements still grows linearly with $n$. Indeed: $0.001n \in \Theta(n)$ and hence $0.001n \not\in o(n)$. See [the page about asymptotic notation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations).

Comment: Thx, for the answer. I will try to check with him about this. He is not actually my professor, I got his lectures from a college site. Because of that I was reluctant to contact him.

Comment: Here  @Steven is right on the money. "Agrees on all but $o(n)$ entries" means that it agrees on all *but* a small fraction (that decreasases as $n$ increases).